# What is different in memory between a string and an array of chars?

Tags: java

What's different about what winds up being referenced in `str` in the first line vs. the second line?

```
char[] str={'A','B','C'};
```

vs.

```
String str= new String("ABC");
```

Comment: What is similar about those two statements??

Comment: One is a String, the other is not.

Answer (score 2):

One is an array of primitives.

The other is a full object with useful functions.

Answer (score 1):

well simply speaking,

`String str= new String("ABC");`
A String is a immutable object (its value can not change) representing a sequence of characters. It has useful String manipulation methods (indexOf, split, etc.)

`char str[]={'A','B','C'};`
A char array is just that : an array of chars. It has a fixed length and you can change its content as you want. It doesn't have any String manipulation method.

Comment: hi Anurag there is no difference in memory?

Comment: A String contains the following:
a char array— thus a separate object— containing the actual characters;
an integer offset into the array at which the string starts;
the length of the string;
another int for the cached calculation of the hash code.

so it is pretty safe to assume that it takes up more space than char array.

Comment: @AbhishekV.Bajaj -- In the naive implementation, the `String` object contains a length field, an offset field, a hash value field, and a reference to a `char[]` array.  The `char[]` array is a separate object that may be shared with other `String` objects (eg, in the case of a substring operation).

Comment: Both of you means Here **String** takes more memory space as compare to **char** array

Comment: you're welcome. Did it correctly answer your question?

Comment: yes this is correct answer of my question

Comment: then you may want  to upvote-accept it and close the thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
char str[]={'A','B','C'};
```

This an array of characters that is three elements long

```
String str= new String("ABC");
```

This is a `String` object that has useful methods that can be called on it.

Comment: It would be nice if people who downvote answers explained their reasoning.